# order(T.decr) not working as expected

Tags: gremlin

The following query works as expected.

```
gremlin> g.V[0].outE.as('e').select{it.timestamp}
==>[e:1]
==>[e:3]
```

However when an order(T.decr) is introduced, the result makes no sense to me. Where did the edge [e:1] go?

```
gremlin> g.V[0].outE.as('e').order(T.decr).select{it.timestamp}
==>[e:3]
==>[e:3]
```

Is this a bug in gremlin or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to have a list of edges sorted by an edge property. In the tinkergraph toy graph we can use the weights property and order the edges decreasing by weights:

```
g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
r = g.V[2].outE.order{it.b.weight<=>it.a.weight}.toList()
```

Output:

```
r.each{println "$it: ${it.weight}"}
e[8][1-knows->4]: 1.0
e[7][1-knows->2]: 0.5
e[9][1-created->3]: 0.4
```

Or if you want to get a specific property of the sorted edges you can simply append the property name, e.g. the edge label:

```
g.V[2].outE.order{it.b.weight<=>it.a.weight}.label
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I needed to move the .as('e') statement so that it was after the order() statement, this is why I was not getting the correct result.

Also as Faber pointed out I needed to use the awful {it.b.timestamp<=>it.a.timestamp} syntax to specify the property I wanted to sort by. Not sure why there is no order('property', T.decr) option.

```
g.V[0].outE.order{it.b.timestamp<=>it.a.timestamp}.as('e').select{it.timestamp}
==>[e:3]
==>[e:1]
```